# Getting 1080p to Work on Netflix

Tags: video, silverlight, netflix

As of recently, I've been having trouble getting HD to work on my Neflix.

I use IE so I can stream in 1080p, but it seems the "HD" button on the Silerlight player has vanished and I evidently cannot get HD video.

Now I've already looked this up and you can force HD by using hotkeys on the player, what I'm not so sure of is which number I'm supposed to manually lock it at.

Right now, I have it set to play at the highest buffering rate assuming that's HD - hopefully 1080p.

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 8.1 is the correct browser for 1080p.

[Netflix gives a system requirements grid](https://help.netflix.com/en/node/23742) that lists IE 11 support.

The hotkey(s) you are referring to:

**CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+S** = Streaming Quality override

**CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+D** = Detailed information about streaming quality and packet information.

You can *force* a specific streaming quality by selecting the highest bitrate and clicking the 'override' button.

Keep in mind that not all videos that Netflix offers are in 1080p, most of their videos aren't. The surefire way to check if you are getting 1080p is to use the 2nd hotkey command and see what *playing bitrate* is currently at.

For example:

> "Playing bitrate (a/v): 64 / 680 ( **res: 720x480**, par: 32x27 )"

Comment: Right. But wouldn't "720x480" NOT be 1080p or is that just your example of showing what resolution you can force it to be?

Comment: I was just showing an example. That was the output from Chrome on a random Star Trek Next Generation Episode. 

Playing bitrate (a/v): 96 / 950 ( res: 1280x720, par: 1x1 )
Is what you would expect for 720p

Playing bitrate (a/v): 96 / 2150 ( res: 1920x1080, par: 1x1 )
Is something like what you would get when you finally get 1080p